# Spring Throws "ERROR SqlExceptionHelper: Already closed" after timeout

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat8

I have a spring application hosted on to the server (Tomcat 8.5). It goes idle if no one uses it. I already knew that timeout will occur if the DB is in idle state for 8 hours (Default timeout of MySQL). As mentioned in [Spring Autoreconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684807/spring-boot-jpa-configuring-auto-reconnect) and [Connection lost overnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221877/connection-lost-overnight-spring-boot-mysql) post i have tried the solution available [here](https://blog.netgloo.com/2015/07/09/spring-boot-communications-link-failure-with-mysql-and-hibernate/).I have tried configuring application.properties but that doesn't bring any solution to the problem.

*(PS:I'm not changing anything other than application.properties in my Spring Application).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If problem doesn't solve even after including properties as in application.properties, Then problem will be solved when including testOnBorrow,validationQuery in application-context.xml located in src/main/resources

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver.classname}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="50"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="-1"/>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="600"/>
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />        
</bean>
```

The solution is to validate connection thread when it is borrowed from thread pool by enabling ***testOnBorrow*** and providing ***validationQuery***.

Answer (score 0):

Well if this

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

or this

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

didnt work maybe try this

Post [SpringBoot 1.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes?fireglass_rsn=true#datasource-binding&fireglass_params%7C&tabid=a4e205a436e3a1f0&application_server_address=p01gwisoapp58a.sgp.dbs.com&popup=true&is_right_side_popup=false&start_with_session_counter=1&anti_bot_permission=16573556486-2436ed41138255b6b580b357b9ef0000b09d3925) names have changed

They have defined new specific namespaces for the four connections pools spring supports: tomcat, hikari, dbcp, dbcp2.

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```