# Spring-boot + JDBC + HSQLDB: How to Verify if Spring Boot is using a Connection Pool?

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, embedded-database

According to [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html):

> **29.1.1 Embedded Database Support**
>
> Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL and Derby databases.
>   You don’t need to provide any connection URLs, simply include a build
>   dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.

and

> **29.1.2 Connection to a production database**
>
> Production database connections can also be auto-configured using a pooling
>   DataSource.
>
> DataSource configuration is controlled by external configuration
>   properties in spring.datasource.*. For example, you might declare the
>   following section in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

> [Tip] You
>   often won’t need to specify the driver-class-name since Spring boot
>   can deduce it for most databases from the url.
>
> [Note] For a pooling
>   DataSource to be created we need to be able to verify that a valid
>   Driver class is available, so we check for that before doing anything.
>   I.e. if you set
>   **spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** then that
>   class has to be loadable.

What if I placed the following in my **application.properties** file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/organization-db
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
```

Will Spring Boot auto-configure a pooling Datasource, since I specified the **spring.datasource.driver-class-name**?
 
Or will it just create a Datasource for the embedded Database driver without connection pooling? 

How do I confirm if Spring Boot is using connection pooling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that as long as there is a supported datasource class on the classpath spring-boot will use it, with tomcat being the preference if none is specified.

The list of supported datasources is given in [DataSourceBuilder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.java), and currently is tomcat, hikari, dbcp and dbcp2.

You could verify if one has been created by looking for `javax.sql.Datasource` implementations from from the application context, though I don't see why one wouldn't.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.java

Comment: Docs say that it will *not* configure the pool if you define a DataSource @Bean anywhere in your app. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database `Additional connection pools can always be configured manually. If you define your own DataSource bean, auto-configuration will not occur.` I had set up Oauth2 and followed a guide and had `@Bean(name = "OAuth")` `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")` `public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {...}` for a JDBC token store and the pool was *not* configured.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your answer Dave.  I'm just starting to learn Spring framework so I'm tinkering with it. This is what I did in **MyApplication.main** method to confirm if Spring Boot is using connection pooling:

```
ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
DataSource dataSource = context.getBean(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource);
```

And I got the following output:

```
DATASOURCE = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@a5b0b86{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=false; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb; username=sa; validationQuery=null; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=30000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }
```

I also tried different configurations with the **application.properties** file and my **build.grade** file to confirm if Spring Boot would still use connection pooling when it auto configures a DataSource and I found out that Spring Boot's auto-configuration always creates a pooling DataSource.

Comment: It will seem to always created a pool if the pool is available, but it will not always configure it! For example: `testOnBorrow=true; validationQuery=/* ping */ SELECT 1;` when auto-configured, but if you create a DataSource bean anywhere in your app, then those will *not* be set, and that spells trouble for MySQL which kills connections after about 8 hours.