# Spring 4 - Cannot start server if DB down

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-4

My tomcat cannot start if DB is down. How i want spring allow to start even the DB is down, and will reconnect the DB once DB its alive?

Im using Spring 4 and BoneCP for the datasource. Below is my jdbc configuration in applicationContext.xml. Im using Tomcat 8.5.

```
<bean id="defaultDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.user}" p:password="${jdbc.pass}"
    p:maxConnectionsPerPartition="${partition.max.connections}"
    p:minConnectionsPerPartition="${partition.min.connections}"
    p:partitionCount="${partition.count}" p:acquireIncrement="${partition.acquire.incrementcount}"
    p:statementsCacheSize="${statements.cache.size}"
    p:idleMaxAgeInMinutes="${idle.max.age.minutes}" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource" ref="defaultDataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your spring process to start even on database error, if you use spring boot ,you can just set like ([doc)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc):

```
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Even reconnect is not recommend ,you can still do it by set (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684807/spring-boot-jpa-configuring-auto-reconnect)):

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
```