# spring-boot-starter-data-jpa : Auto Reconnect

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, properties-file

In old spring version we can do it using the code below into application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 3600000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

but now? How to do it in new spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE ?

Answer (score 0):

add tomcat

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true 
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Note that the use of autoReconnect is not recommended.
'1.4+ defines specific namespaces for the four connections pools Spring Boot supports: tomcat, hikari, dbcp, dbcp2 (dbcp is deprecated as of 1.5).'
more in: [Spring Boot JPA - configuring auto reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684807/spring-boot-jpa-configuring-auto-reconnect)