# Release Idle DataSource in Multitenant Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I am working in Multi Tenant Spring Boot application. I am using the concept of one DB per Tenant approach. I have configured the dynamic database creation and connection. Also those database configurations are stored in a Map. Now I would like to implement an approach to clear DataSource which is idle for long time?

Comment: hi, please read here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and then edit your question :)

Comment: instead of storing database connection details inside Map you can also use **another database table** which will provide dynamic connectivity based on `tenantId` and only 1 datasource will be loaded

Comment: @emotionlessbananas storing the details at anywhere is fine. But my requirement is how to find the particular datasource is idle for long time?

Comment: in that case you can look into `test-while-idle` and `validation-query` property

Comment: Do I have to initialize every datasource like the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48413427/7458887

Comment: no, you only have to call 1 database at run time. rest will be idle by default. This is SAAS based solution must look into it

Comment: Yeah It's a SAAS based application. We chose the one tenant per DB model. But how to use database resources efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you create Datasource and attempt to store them in a map,

whilst you create DS. you can mention

basicDataSource.setMinIdle(multitenantConnectionPoolConfig.getMinIdle());

So the connection pools ensure only active connections exist in the pool after the min Idle time expires.