# After SQL server restart EntityManager not able to reconnect with datasource in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have created one **spring-boot** application with **datasource routing**. I have used **javax.persistence.EntityManager** to retrive data from database using store-procedure. After restarting sql server, EntityManager fail to retrive data from database using store-procedure.
I have used both property **TestOnBorrow** and **ValidationQuery**.

RoutingDataSourceCode

```
public class MessagingChildDataSourceConfig{
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessagingChildDataSourceConfig.class);


@Autowired
protected MessagingDataSourceUtil util;

@Autowired
protected JPAProperties jpaProperties;

@Bean(name = "messageDatasource")
@PostConstruct
public DataSource messageDatasource() throws SQLException {

    Map<Object, Object> datasourceMap = new HashMap<>();

    DataSource msgChildDataSources = DataSourceBuilder.create()
    .url("URL")
    .username("USER")
    .password("PASS")
    .build();

    datasourceMap.put("testDataSOurce", msgChildDataSources);

    MessagingRoutingDataSource datasource = new MessagingRoutingDataSource();
    DataSource msgDefaultDataSource = util.defaultDataSource();
    util.setTypeSpecificProperties(msgDefaultDataSource);
    datasource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(msgDefaultDataSource);
    datasource.setTargetDataSources(datasourceMap);

    datasource.afterPropertiesSet();
    return datasource;
}

@Bean(name = "messageEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean messageEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("messageDatasource") DataSource childDatasource) {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = builder.dataSource(childDatasource)
            .packages(getPackages()) // for entity package
            .persistenceUnit("messagesdbTest").properties(CommonUtil.getJPAProperties(jpaProperties)).build();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = "messageTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager messageTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("messageEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory childEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(childEntityManagerFactory);
}

@Bean(name = "channelEntityManager")
public EntityManager entityManager(@Qualifier("messageEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory){
    return factory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
}

public  String[] getPackages(){
    return new String[]{"com.asite.abc.data.entity"};
}
```

}

Get data from database using store procedure.

```
public class ChannelService {


@Qualifier("channelEntityManager")
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED, transactionManager = MessagingStringPool.CHANNEL_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
public void getUserAccessibleDCs(Long channelId, Long projectId) {

    StoredProcedureQuery query = this.entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("channelUserAccessibleDCs");
    this.entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);
    query.setParameter("channel_id", channelId);
    query.execute(); //**Error from this line**

}
```

}

**Properties:**

```
spring.datasource.password=Pass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true 
spring.datasource.username=Username
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

**ERROR** while execute store-procedure query using EntityManager, After restart sql server. Error log

```
    11-09-2018 14:57:50.579 [pool-14-thread-32] ERROR c.a.m.c.c.ChannelMessageCommand.execute - Error while converting JSON to object
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:224)
    at com.asite.message.channel.entity.service.ChannelService.getUserAccessibleDCs(ChannelService.java:619)
    at com.asite.message.channel.entity.service.ChannelService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ab52f291.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.asite.message.channel.entity.service.ChannelService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$303bc2d0.getUserAccessibleDCs(<generated>)
    at com.asite.message.session.service.channel.ChannelSessionService.setChannelUserAccessibleDCs(ChannelSessionService.java:1140)
    at com.asite.message.command.channel.ChannelMessageCommand.execute(ChannelMessageCommand.java:112)
    at com.asite.message.command.channel.ChannelMessageCommand.execute(ChannelMessageCommand.java:44)
    at com.asite.message.TextMessageProcessor.lambda$executeMessageCommand$77(TextMessageProcessor.java:95)
    at com.asite.message.TextMessageProcessor$$Lambda$80/1154803940.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:724)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareCall(SQLServerConnection.java:2990)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareCall(SQLServerConnection.java:2593)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684807/spring-boot-jpa-configuring-auto-reconnect