# DB connection is getting lost after some time in spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

We are facing this problem when the application starts DB connection gets created and after some time connection gets closed by the server. We are using Postgres in Amazon RDS.

```
2019-12-13 14:02:33.385  WARN 1 --- [io-8080-exec-41] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2019-12-13 14:02:33.386 ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-41] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
2019-12-13 14:02:33.391 ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-41] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:669) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:183) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1985) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1915) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:602) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at
```

Comment: Please show the db configuration

Comment: What is the version of Spring Boot you are using? Also what are the versions of the db dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following configuration to let the spring boot reconnect to the DB.

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

You can find the explanation here: [Spring Boot JPA - configuring auto reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684807/spring-boot-jpa-configuring-auto-reconnect).