# Springboot Application fails after database restart

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, tomcat, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

We have developed a Springboot Java application and using 1.5.6 version. Using spring data jpa and provided custom implementation as well.

If I restart DB and execute some operation then it throws an below error for the services which are annotated with **@Transactional annotation**. Though, its working well for other DAO repository call which are not annotated with this annotation. **Also, if I restart my spring boot application then it works fine.**

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.findOne(Unknown Source)
        at au.com.outware.swepad.tasks.WorkOrderManagerTask.taskFetchAndProcessWorkOrderDetails(WorkOrderManagerTask.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:724)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:2615)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
2018-10-29 16:00:08,995 WARN pool-30-thread-1  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2018-10-29 16:00:08,996 ERROR pool-30-thread-1  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The connection is closed.
2018-10-29 16:30:00,017 INFO pool-13-threa
```

Herewith sharing the method which causing this issue:

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED, transactionManager = AppConstants.CHILD_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    public Map<String, Object> getParentIdFromChildsId(String childIds, int userId, int projectID) {
            jdbcTemplate.query("EXEC getParentIdFromChildsId?,?,?", new Object[] { childIds, userId, projectID },
                    (rs, rowNum) -> {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(0, rs.getString("parent_id"));
                        list.add(1, rs.getString("box_id"));
                        list.add(2, rs.getString("permission"));
                        return list;
                    });
   }
```

Also we are Using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource connection pool.

Let me know if other details required. Please help me on this.

Comment: The Spring Boot version is seriously outdated, which probably also means your dependencies are outdated and therefore full of known vulnerabilities. Please upgrade to a current version and make it part of your release plan to upgrade to the most recent version on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because all the connections in your connection pool are broken after restarting the database. I can't really explain why it doesn't happen with other methods, but maybe it's just a timing issue, where the connections get closed and reopened after they failed once.

If my suspicion is correct setting [`testOnBorrow`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes) to `true` should solve the issue. [This answer describes how to do that in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22687418/66686):

> ```
> spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true 
> spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
> ```

Comment: thanks @Jens Schauder for your response. I have already this properties in my app properties. But, it has not helped me.