# spring datasource validationtimeout max value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to set the max value for spring datasource validation-timeout in application.yml but not able to find that max value setting anywhere, I searched many sites all speaks about the default value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724168/1775344 is not what you are looking for?

Comment: No there it is mentioned for spring.datasource.validationQuery but my config is for spring.datasource.validation-timeout

Comment: There is no such property you need to set the specific one for your datasource, in your case probably Hikari.