# Intermittent connection issues from Springboot to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a springboot application which connects to a postgres DB.Connection pool used is Hikari.
I have a select query running every 5 minutes.Though it gets executed properly most of the times, i encounter a PSQLException intermittently

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:333) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:132) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.isValid(PgConnection.java:1364) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:153) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:155) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:462) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at com.***.***.batch.job.CacheRefreshWatcher.cacheRefreshSchedular(CacheRefreshWatcher.java:38) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor344.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:514) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendSync(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1363) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:304) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        ... 29 common frames omitted

2019-12-14 07:55:00.015  WARN 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@48cf96e3 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2019-12-14 22:00:00.017  WARN 1 --- [   scheduling-1] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         : Validating connection.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:333) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:132) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.isValid(PgConnection.java:1364) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:153) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:155) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:462) [spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at com.adessa.promiseengine.batch.job.CacheRefreshWatcher.cacheRefreshSchedular(CacheRefreshWatcher.java:38) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor344.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:514) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendSync(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1363) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:304) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
        ... 29 common frames omitted

2019-12-14 22:00:00.018  WARN 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3029eb50 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
```

Below is my hikari properties

```
 hikari:
      minimum-idle: 5
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      idle-timeout: 600000
      max-lifetime: 550000
      connection-timeout: 600000
```

Application is hosted in an on premise server connected to an on prem db, also its hosted  in AKS connecting to a Azure Postgres DB.
Error is seen in both deployments.
Can someone help me understand why is this happening and suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi Shamil, it tells you what is wrong via your logs: `HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@48cf96e3 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.` Did you try to go with HikariCP default parameters first and then, one after the other, test your custom values?

Comment: @DavidArtmann the hikari default maxLifeTime's default value is much higher,also Hikari suggests to use a shorter maxLifeTime than DB imposed wait timeouts.But my DB doesnt have any timeouts set.
Apparently this is an issue with postgres library where they should return a true or false on PgConnection.isValid, but an exception is coming out.

Comment: Then you know what to do, like I already suggested (but for a different question) in my answer. Just catch the exception and reopen a db connection. This is a common practice: instead of relying on connection validation use the connection and catch any exceptions (maybe also distinguish between them) and reopen it if necessary. Btw PgConnection's docu tells you that the method can throw an exception.