# Intermittent error when connecting to Aurora rds from springboot application

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

Getting this error intermittently from my spring boot application running on Amazon EKS trying to connect to Aurora RDS (14.9), jdbc version: 42.3.8

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection,stack-trace=java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
> at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:111)
> at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
> at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
> at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:284)
> at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
> at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
> at com.example.TestClass.executeInTransaction(RepositoryImpl.java:145)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
> ... 3 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:382)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.execSQLQuery(PgConnection.java:476)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.execSQLQuery(PgConnection.java:469)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getTransactionIsolation(PgConnection.java:913)
> at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.getTransactionIsolation(NewProxyConnection.java:1279)
> at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:73)
> at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
> at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
> ... 22 more
> Caused by: java.io.EOFException
> at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:455)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2119)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
> ... 34 more

Comment: There is not enough information here to make an educated guess as to what the issue. We would need to see how you are creating the database connection at a minimum, especially information about if you're using connection pooling or not. I found a similar article that gives you quite a few good options to look into for the specific error message you're getting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285340/postgresql-exception-an-i-o-error-occured-while-sending-to-the-backend